# Implementing InstanceIDListenerService in Appcelerator

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to take care of updated GCM tokens in my appcelerator project. 
As far as I understand I should create a service with an intent-filter like this:

```
<service url="testservice.js" type="standard">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Do I need to make sure I get the actual onTokenRefresh() or is it enough to take care of the GCM token update when my service is started?

Is it possible to get the onTokenRefresh() call in javascript or do I need to implement this in a native module extending the InstanceIDListenerService class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked several [GCM modules](http://gitt.io/search?q=gcm) but none seem to use onTokenRefresh. Any way, you would need to wrap this in a Titanium module. It's not something you can access from JS.